# Error in searching in datagrid

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm making a search in my system but it said:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

I can only enter 1 digit and after I erase or enter another digit it pops up the error.

Here my code:

```
  Try
        For row As Integer = 0 To dgv_room.Rows.Count
            If dgv_room.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Substring(0, tbx_search.Text.Length) = tbx_search.Text Then
                dgv_room.Rows(row).Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is happening when your search value won't be found in the gridview and therefore the loop will go through all of the rows.

However you are looping from 0 to the count of rows in the gridview, but the row collection in the the gridview is zero-based, therefore you need to reduce the amount of iterations through the loop by one:

```
  Try
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv_room.SelectedRows
            row.Selected = False
        Next
        For row As Integer = 0 To dgv_room.Rows.Count - 1
            If dgv_room.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(tbx_search.Text) Then
                dgv_room.Rows(row).Selected = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

For example:

Lets say your gridview has 5 rows in it, if your search text won't exist in any of them then each iteration will be as follows:

```
row = 0 > checks dgv_room.Rows(0)...
row = 1 > checks dgv_room.Rows(1)...
row = 2 > checks dgv_room.Rows(2)...
row = 3 > checks dgv_room.Rows(3)...
row = 4 > checks dgv_room.Rows(4)...
row = 5 > checks dgv_room.Rows(5)... (error here as a Row in the Rows collection with an idex of 5 doesn't exist)
```

Comment: i tried it i can now type more digts but the select rows still in the top and when i use backspace it popups again.

Comment: Ok, does the data in `.Cells(0)` just contain the data you need to search for? If so then you should be able to remove the `.Substring(0, tbx_search.Text)` part of your code.

Comment: sorry but i still dont get it, how can i loop it back if their nothing found? and i cant use back space. this codes is for search

Comment: i think it has, sorry im just new in vb.net,i try to remove .Substring(0, tbx_search.Text) to my code and now its not highlighting the entire cell i want to search

Comment: In that case the change your IF statement to `If dgv_room.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString.Contains(tbx_search.Text) Then`. The original way will just select a row if it is a 100% match, not a partial, which is what you probably want for a search system! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/errorxp.png/ i just provide a screen shots for you i cant explain in words sorry. the problem is still that the search highlighting is incorrect

Comment: Ah, you need to unselect existing selected rows, I will update my answer to show this.

Comment: lastly it can only read the first letter
i put the code on my  tbx_search_KeyPress so i was planning to change the
syntax in "IF" statement using "LIKE" in sql is it possible?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here as the `.Contains()` does a similar thing. I would suggest putting that in a seperate question as it is deviating from the original question a bit too much. If my answer has answered your original question then please accept it. :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
If dgv_room.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value.ToString.contains(tbx_search.Text) Then
```

Contains is better. I could not understand your second question, but try this.

Comment: imageshack.us/photo/my-images/191/errorxp.png i just provide a screen shots for you i cant explain in words sorry. the problem is still that the search highlighting is incorrect